# Should I report an old bug that is still present?

Tags: unity, bug-reporting

Hot corners enabled via the Unity tweak tool in Ubuntu 16.04 do not work properly after rebooting. I've seen that this bug has been present since 14.04 and it has been reported on Launchpad, but it was just "confirmed". Should I report the bug again?

Comment: What is the bug you're referring to?  I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1305438) one, but it has expired.

Comment: Yes it is that, however I've completely stopped using unity tweak tool since in one occasion it completely crashed the interface. I guess I'll wait until those "tweaks" are available in the regular settings.

Comment: I haven't experienced crashes with Unity tweak tool, however, as you described, hot corners are working inconsistently.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For people interested in this issue,  I opened this bug [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1606391)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the bug has already been reported on Launchpad, don't file a duplicate. Instead, you should click on "Does this bug affect you?" and then click on "Yes, it affects me". If you want to provide more details in the form of screenshots or logs, then make a post on the bug report with these details so that the devs have more useful information to work with.

Comment: Seconded.  Please note that you need to register on `https://launchpad.net/` to be able to vote on bugs.